# msgbox asking for user input in specific format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a quick little macro that asks the user for an input, and then copies this to a specific cell (B14 in Sheet1). Here's what I've got so far:

```
Option Explicit    
Sub updatesheet()

Dim vReply As String     
vReply = InputBox("Enter period (format: Q4 2010) to update, or hit enter to escape")
If vReply = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B14").Value = vReply    
End Sub
```

I was also wondering if there is some way I can include a check to make sure the user input is in the correct format, and if not, flags up an error and asks the user to re-enter?

Help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this, you were very close (rather than `Inputbox` you just needed to use `vReply` when writing to Sheet1 B14)

**Updated** Overhauled to de-hmmm:

1. Uses `Application.InputBox` rather than 'InputBox' as this provides the coder with more optionality. But nice to have in this instance rather than critcal
2. Uses a Regex to ensure that the string is of the form "Q[1-4]" with a year ranging from 2010-2020  (to update to 2011-2013 use `"^Q[1-4]\s20[11-13]{2}$"`. The "q" test is case insensitive
3. I've added a default entry of "Q1 2011" to the prompt that calcuates using the currentd ate, `Int((Month(Now()) - 1) / 3) + 1 & " " & Year(Now())` returns Q4 2011 . You can remove this prompt if desired
4. A `Do` loop is used to test invalid strings, if an invalid string is supplied than the `strTitle` variable of "Please retry"" is used to let the user know that prior attempts were invalid (the msg doesn't show the first time through as the user is yet to make a mistake)
5. Pressing Cancel triggers a separate exit message to let the user know the code has terminated early

   ```
    Option Explicit
   Sub Rattle_and_hmmmm()
   Dim strReply As String
   Dim strTitle As String
   Dim objRegex As Object
   Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With objRegex
       .ignorecase = True
       .Pattern = "^Q[1-4]\s20[10-20]{2}$"
       Do
           If strReply <> vbNullString Then strTitle = "Please retry"
           strReply = Application.InputBox("Enter period (format: Q4 2010) to update, or hit enter to escape", strTitle, "Q" & Int((Month(Now()) - 1) / 3) + 1 & " " & Year(Now()), , , , , 2)
           If strReply = "False" Then
               MsgBox "User hit cancel, exiting code", vbCritical
               Exit Sub
           End If
       Loop Until .test(strReply)
   End With
   Sheets("Sheet1").[b14].Value = UCase$(strReply)
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Is there a simple line I can add incase the user enters the q lowercase?

Comment: I have updated code so that the msgbox will accept "Q2 2010" or "q2 2010", but will enter in "Q2 2010" as the result for both cases

Comment: `GoTo`...not very elegant. you show me that in an interview and for sure you're not hired :-/

Comment: It's fit for purpose, I'm only an accountant ;)

Comment: @heavyarms I reckon for your own sake you should try to get your exits down to as few as possible. You will thank yourself later.

Comment: @Remou, I do agree. I intend to come back to this one (with a regexp and dealing with the goto/exits) as my existing sense of hmmm has been reinforced by other feedback.

Comment: "existing sense of hmmm" great line :D

Answer (score 4):

I have difficulties with both the earlier answers.

I agree that validation is essential; the user might type "2011-4" if they do not think hard enough about the prompt.  Checking that its format is "Q# ####" is definitely a step in the right direction.  However:

I would have pointed out that this level of checking is not enough.  "Q5 1234", for example, would match this format.  "Q5 1234" would suggest the user was trying to break the system but "Q4 2101" is an easy error to make.

The Like operator is your only choice with Excel 2003 but with later versions I would recommend considering regular expressions.  I have been trying them out with VB 2010.  I do not deny they are a struggle to understand but they do so much for you. Perhaps heavyarms has enough learning on his plate at the moment but I would still suggest looking at some of the recent questions about their use.

As used in the earlier answers, InputBox does not achieve heavyarms' objective.  If I typed "Q4 2101" instead of "Q4 2011" and the macro was enhanced to check for impossible dates, I would not know of my simple error unless the error message included the value I typed.  Also I could not edit "Q4 2101" to the value I meant to type.  The syntax for InputBox is vReply = InputBox(Prompt, Title, Default, ...).  So if I was going to recommend the use of the Like operator, I would suggest:

```
Sub updatesheet()

  Dim vReply As String
  Dim Prompt As String
  Dim Title As String
  Dim UpdateQuarter As Integer
  Dim UpdateYear As Integer

  ' I have found users respond better to something like "Qn ccyy" 
  Prompt = "Enter period (format: Qn ccyy) to update, or hit enter to escape"
  ' I find a title that gives context can be helpful.
  Title = "Update sheet"

  vReply = InputBox(Prompt, Title)

  Do While True
    ' I have had too many users add a space at the end of beginning of a string
    ' or an extra space in the middle not to fix these errors for them.
    ' Particularly as spotting extra spaces can be very difficult. 
    vReply = UCase(Trim(VReply))
    vReply = Replace(vReply, "  ", " ") ' Does not cater for three spaces 
    If Len(vReply) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If vReply Like "Q# ####" Then
      ' I assume your macro will need these value so get them now
      ' so you can check them.
      UpdateQuarter = Mid(vReply, 2, 1)
      UpdateYear = Mid(vReply, 4)
      ' The check here is still not as full as I would include in a macro
      ' released for general use.  I assume "Q4-2011" is not valid because
      ' the quarter is not finished yet.  Is "Q3-2011" available yet?  I
      ' would use today's date to calculate the latest possible quarter.
      ' I know "You cannot make software foolproof because fools are so
      ' ingenious" but I have learnt the hard way that you must try.
      If UpdateQuarter >= 1 And UpdateQuarter <= 4 And _
         UpdateYear >= 2009 And UpdateYear <= 2012 Then
        Exit Do
      Else
        ' Use MsgBox to output error message or include it in Prompt
      End If
    Else
      ' Use MsgBox to output error message or include it in Prompt
    End If
    vReply = InputBox(Prompt, Title, vReply)
  Loop

End Sub
```

Lastly, I rarely use InputBox because Forms, once mastered, are so easy to create and offer far more control.

Comment: Thanks Tony, as always you've given me a lot to think about. Will definetely look into forms going forward.

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive answer full of good advice.  One small note: to better handle multiple spaces use `Do While vReply Like "*  *" vReply = Replace(vReply, "  ", " ") Loop`

Comment: Good point.  I had thought of using a loop to remove all double spaces but decided I had given heavyarms enough to think about for one answer.  He always thanks me for my answers but I bet I make his brain hurt.  Thanks for the +1.  I have only been a member for 2 months; I must start reviewing answers and upvoting those I consider good.

Comment: Tony,  you do raise valid points. I went with 'Like' rather than my standard regexp as the query asked to validate a *format* rather than the actual value itself. For example Is 2016 ok or not as a value. Plus fixing non-valid formats (ie extra spaces) is a slippery slope, for example should a Q12010 be automatically made Q1 2010, Q1 2011h into Q1 2011 etc. That said on a later related question I did test the qx portion to ensure x was 1-4. I will update this with a regexp (+1 btw)

Comment: @brettdj.  Is there a correct level of detail in an answer?  You answer a lot of questions in which you provide a just enough information to point the OP in the right direction.  I answer fewer questions but talk around the problem.  Partly this is because I am retired and have the time.  Partly this is because I regularly had clients ask for what they thought they could have rather than for what they wanted.  Only by talking around the problem could I tease out what they really wanted.  Perhaps they need both of us.

Comment: @TonyDallimore. Absolutely! The forums work as well as they do ideas get teased out and improved by collaboration (especially with different styles) much more than they would by individual efforts.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub updatesheet()
    Dim vReply As String
    Do
        'edit: added UCase on INputBox
        vReply = UCase(InputBox("Enter period (format: Q4 2010) to update, or hit enter to escape"))
    Loop Until Len(vReply) = 0 Or vReply Like "Q# ####"
    If vReply = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    'continue...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this one out too! Looks more complex, but always worth picking up something new :D

Comment: I'd add brettdjs modification to the "Loop Until" line:
`UCase$(vReply) Like "Q# ####"`
so it accepts lowercase and uppercase 'q'.

Comment: I would not do it like that. See my edit. BTW, Like is not case sensitive, AFAIK.

Comment: Like is case sensitive with Excel 2003.

Comment: @Tony: ok. then the `UCase(InputBox(...))` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: As user cancel is a very different beast than a failed centry code then different handling techniques should be employed to distinguish between these paths.

Comment: @Tony: what if you specify `option compare text`? :-)

Comment: @PatrickHonorez  I have carefully read the documentation. It clearly states that `Option Compare Text` makes `Like` case insensitive. However, I would not take advantage of this. (1) Over the years, I have written hundreds of useful subroutines and functions which I keep in a library. I do not want to have to think about which `Option` statements I need or are forbidden for a macro to function correctly. I use `Option Explicit` and nothing else.

Comment: (2) `Like` has not been carried forward to VB.Net. It is very unlikely that Microsoft would remove `Like` from VBA but I still prefer to restrict myself to operators with a future. (3) `Regex` is better featured and better documented than `Like`. I agree `Regex` is more difficult to use until you become familiar with it but I consider the learning curve to be worth the benefits.