# Using Input Box to Filter Text - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter a pre-determined column using a query from a user (Input Box)

Ex: Filter column "L" with a user input text "Joey".
Can anyone guide me as to what needs to be done? This is the code I was trying...

```
Set wSheetStart = ActiveSheet
Set rFilterHeads = Range("L1", Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft))

With wSheetStart
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    rFilterHeads.AutoFilter
    strCriteria = InputBox("Enter Criteria")
    If strCriteria = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    rFilterHeads.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=strCriteria         
End With
```

Comment: and what doesn't work as expected in your current code?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8532986/78522

Comment: @Jmax I had to also tweak the strCriteria code that's one of the reasons it gave an error.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop + `Like` to limit entry to whatever you need.

```
Do
    strCriteria = UCase(InputBox("Enter criteria"))
Loop Until Len(strCriteria) = 0 Or strCriteria Like "?????"
If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then Exit Sub
'continue...
```